# After adding a new row to the left affects my DataRange in my Excel Macro

Tags: vba, excel

I created an excel spreadsheet with a macro. The code worked fine until the end user added a column. I then modified the code to account for the shift in columns. Everything worked except for the Data Range Object. I changed the Range to one column and now it is reading the column to the right of it. 
They used to be columns A, B, I. They now read columns C, D, K. Has anyone had this problem before? 
Here is my Macro Code as of now and after the new column:

```
Sub Transfer2NewWorkbook()
Dim currentsheet As String
Dim newsheet As String
Dim analysisDate As String
Dim initial As String
Dim aInitial() As String      
Dim analystInit As String
Dim aBatch() As String
Dim batch As String
Dim batchNo As String
Dim key As Variant
Dim ikey As Variant

Dim SrowN As String
Dim rowN As Integer
Dim rowD As String
Dim mKey As String
Dim wb As Object
Dim dataRangeN As Range, dataRangeB As Range, dataRangeI As Range
Dim dataN As Object
Set dataN = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Dim dataB As Object
Set dataB = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Dim dataT As Object
Set dataT = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Dim dataI As Object
Set dataI = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Dim teststring As String



' Grab and Create filenames
currentsheet = ActiveWorkbook.Name
If Right$(currentsheet, 1) = "s" Then
    currentsheet = Left(currentsheet, Len(currentsheet) - 4)
Else
    currentsheet = Left(currentsheet, Len(currentsheet) - 5)
End If

newsheet = currentsheet & "-" & "uploadable"

' Grab data from original spreadsheet
analysisDate = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 10).Value

initial = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 3).Value
aInitial = Split(initial, "/")
analystInit = aInitial(1)

batch = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 5).Value
aBatch = Split(batch, ":")
batchNo = aBatch(1)

Set dataRangeN = Range("B:B")
Set dataRangeB = Range("C:C")
Set dataRangeI = Range("J:J")


For i = 4 To dataRangeB.Rows.Count
    If Not IsEmpty(dataRangeB(i, 2)) Then
        If StrComp(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(i, 3).Value, "End") = 0 Then
            Exit For
        ElseIf StrComp(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(i, 3).Value, "Blank") = 0 Then
             If StrComp(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(i, 2).Value, "Unseeded") = 0 Or StrComp(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(i, 2).Value, "Seeded") = 0 Then
                If Not IsEmpty(dataRangeI(i, 1)) Then
                    dataN.Add i, ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(i, 2).Value
                    dataB.Add i, ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(i, 3).Value
                    dataI.Add i, ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(i, 10).Value
                End If
             End If
        ElseIf StrComp(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(i, 3).Value, "Check") = 0 Then
            If StrComp(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(i, 2).Value, "Std") = 0 Then
                If Not IsEmpty(dataRangeI(i, 1)) Then
                    dataN.Add i, ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(i, 2).Value
                    dataB.Add i, ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(i, 3).Value
                    dataI.Add i, ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(i, 10).Value
                End If
            End If
        ElseIf StrComp(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(i, 3).Value, "DUP") = 0 Then
            rowD = dataB.Keys()(dataB.Count - 1)
            If StrComp(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(i - 1, 2).Value, "CBOD") = 0 Then
                dataN.Add rowD, "DUP-CBOD"
            ElseIf StrComp(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(i - 1, 2).Value, "BOD") = 0 Then
                dataN.Add rowD, "DUP-BOD"
            End If
        Else
            If Len(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(i, 3).Value) = 16 Then
                    dataT.Add i, ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(i + 1, 2).Value
                    dataB.Add i, ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(i, 3).Value
                    dataI.Add i, ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(i, 10).Value
            End If
        End If
    Else
        If StrComp(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(i, 2).Value, "DUP") = 0 Then
            If ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(i, 3).Value <> "" Then
                rowD = dataB.Keys()(dataB.Count - 1)
                If StrComp(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(i - 1, 2).Value, "CBOD") = 0 Then
                    dataN.Add rowD, "DUP-CBOD"
                ElseIf StrComp(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(i - 1, 2).Value, "BOD") = 0 Then
                    dataN.Add rowD, "DUP-BOD"
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
Next i

' Open new spreadsheet
Set wb = 
 Workbooks.Add("\\******\ops\envcom\exec\envcom\LAB\BOD\uploadtemp.xlsx")

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(2, 1).Value = analysisDate
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(2, 2).Value = analystInit
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(2, 4).Value = batchNo

rowN = 4
For Each key In dataB.Keys
    mKey = key
    If dataI.Exists(key) Then
        SrowN = CStr(rowN)
        If dataN.Exists(key) Or dataN.Exists(mKey) Then
            If dataN(key) = "" Then
                ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(SrowN, 1).Value = dataN(mKey)
            Else
                ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(SrowN, 1).Value = dataN(key)
            End If
        End If
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(SrowN, 2).Value = dataB(key)
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(SrowN, 3).Value = dataT(key)
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(SrowN, 4).Value = dataI(key)
        rowN = CInt(SrowN)
        rowN = rowN + 1
    End If
Next

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs 
("\\******\ops\envcom\exec\envcom\LAB\BOD\Uploadables\" & newsheet & ".xlsx")

End Sub
```

Comment: Did you just update the `Range` assignments, or did you update all the magic numbers for the columns too?  Note that you have a single column assignment with `Set dataRangeB = Range("C:C")` and then index outside of that column later with `dataRangeB(i, 2)`. I suspect you'll need to step through everything with the debugger to make get the indexing correct again. Not much anyone here can do without a lot more information about the data.

Comment: I recommend using a variable and number system to define the columns, rows for that matter, you can make your changes at the top of the code and not have to chase it through the module.  I know that is a pain, but a pain that is well worth it.

Comment: If you never want to go through this again and you know the headers of the columns you want, write a little script that assigns the col number in a simple loop upon a instr > 0 condition.  I have had to do this on a few occasions, where I am actually inserting new columns (adding months to financial sheets), you can run the script whenever you want as many times as you want, especially if you are inserting or deleting, same things for particular rows of course.

Comment: @Comintern, you were right. I changed that dataRangeB(i, 2) to dataRangeB(i,1) and EUREKA!. I don't understand how my eyes missed that. You are correct I was out of index.